# Navigation drawer works in Android 6.0(1080x1920) but does not work in Android 4 (480x600)

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

Here is the Main Activity xml file where Navigation drawer is called :

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <include
            layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />


        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
            app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"
            android:layout_marginTop="56dp"/>

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And it includes the following XML file into the above :

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.vinitmandlesha.myins.MainActivity">

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Navigation Drawer is unresponsive in Android 4 (480x600) device but perfectly fines in Android 6 (1080x1920) device. Where is the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Define diffrent dimens.xml file for both devices. like values-w820,w540,sw360,sw240... and change values

```
<dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">15dp</dimen>
<dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">15dp</dimen>
<dimen name="fab_margin">15dp</dimen>
<!-- Default screen margins, per the Android Design guidelines. -->
<dimen name="nav_header_vertical_spacing">16dp</dimen>
<dimen name="nav_header_height">160dp</dimen>
<dimen name="nav_drawer_width">260dp</dimen>
```

Comment: Do I have to change values for each resolution type ?

Comment: Please add detail explaination as I am newbie to android development. If possible give example.

Comment: create different layout in android studio one layout and other extra large layout. and in values folder also two dimens.xml  file where you can find drawer margin . so change activity_horizontal_margin 16dp for small layout and 64dp for xlarge layout.

Comment: I did what you have mentioned above. It is not working.The problem is that the layout appears properly and navigation works fine if the android version is lollipop or marshmellow irrespective of what the device size, resolution or pixel density.

Comment: But, when the app is installed in jellybean or lower version, then main layout overlap the toolbar that contains the hamburger icon for navigation drawer even if I used the same device type that has same resolution, size and pixel density that worked fine in lollipop or higher version. So I cannot used the navigation drawer. Please give some valid reason for this mishap !

Comment: See the image below to understand the problem : http://i.stack.imgur.com/ZqZDd.png